# Deserializing 100s of protocol buffers messages each with small data for single webpage view, Is it right way to do it?

Tags: java, database, serialization, protocol-buffers

For generating data for a single page view for a high traffic public website,  I'm deserializing hundreds of protocol buffers messages. Most of such messages contain only a bunch of(just 3-5) integers or strings. Such protocol buffers messages are stored in database & protocol buffers is simply used for storing related data as a single field in database.

But serializing/deserializing hundreds of protocol buffer messages for a single webpage on a high trafffic site, is not so performant, Is protocol buffers the right technology to use for this purpose ?

What should be the right performant way to store a bunch of related data together in database as a single field ?

Comment: Protobufs is well-optimized for small messages, so this shouldn't be an issue. Could you share more information about the performance problems you're seeing? Maybe run a profile to see where the CPU is spending time?

Comment: I haven't yet profiled to check out whether that's really creating problems for me.. but I am seeking a general consensus whether this looks like the right implementation.. deserializing several hundered small protobuf messages to generate a single webpage on high traffic site ..?

Answer (score 0):

Protobufs is well-optimized for small messages. Parsing 100 small messages shouldn't take much more time than parsing a single message of 100x the size. I would worry more about the performance of your database.